# Unification of the 'X Window System' tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) has picked up a few tag for its self on SO; [x11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x11), [xwindows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xwindows), [xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xlib), [xorg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xorg), [x.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x.org), [xserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xserver) and I am sure there are a more variations in use. What I think is even worse is that 'x-window-system' has simply become a synonym for 'x11'!

It is currently very hard to find quality QnA for X related topics due to the many tags. If they where merged together it would vastly improve the ease at which the valuable nuggets of information can be found. All told, only 1775 questions are tagged, not even that many; that was counting questions multiple times if tagged multiple times.

I am aware that it could be consider too broad a tag for everything 'x window system' related to come under the one tag, but I do not believe there is enough traffic in these tags to warrant such a fragmented system.

In my opinion, there is no doubt that the one 'official' tag should be 'x-window-system'. The rest should be synonyms of 'x-window-sytem'. Though I will admit that perhaps 'xserver' is potentially a valid separate tag.

To preventively counter suggestions that the 'x11' tag should be kept as the primary one. X11 is just a version, a very long lived version perhaps, but just a version non the less. X org have even stated that the 'preferred' terms be 'X', 'X Window System' or 'X Version 11'.

so, in short:

Can the 'x-windows-system' -> 'x11' synonym be reversed.
Can the following tags be made synonyms of 'x-window-system'; xwidnows, xlib, xorg, x.org xserver.

**edit**

So, based on feedback so far, some subtle changes need to be made to this request. 'x.org' should be made a synonym of 'xorg'.

I belive there also needs to be some clear guide lines (tag wiki will do the job) on what these tags are for. 'x-windows-system' is for question about 'x' in general, any implementation of the specification, or about the specification in general. 'xorg' should be used only for questions on that specific  implementation.

I still stand my view that 'xserver' should be synonym for 'x-window-system'. These questions would still be about 'X' in general and there is not enough of them to warrant a separate tag, especially as many are not about the display server any way. Though again, perhaps just stricter policing of this tag would suffice.

Comment: Wouldn't xlib be about that library in particular and not X in general?  The same could be said about xserver.

Comment: Xlib really shouldn't be merged in; it would be like merging jQuery into DOM manipulation! While Xlib is very popular for using the X protocol, there are other libraries like XCB that can be used instead. In fact, you don't have to use any library at all; it's just a network protocol, after all.

Answer (score 2):

Thought it is by far the most installed server X.org is not the only one (not only is there the unforked Xfree86 but there are multiple commercial implementations).

I am in favor of making [x-window-system](/questions/tagged/x-window-system) senior to [x11](/questions/tagged/x11), [xwindows](/questions/tagged/xwindows), [xserver](/questions/tagged/xserver) and perhaps even [xlib](/questions/tagged/xlib), but I don't think that the X.org specific varients should map to the highly general [x-window-system](/questions/tagged/x-window-system).